# Figure out the processing chain for receiving mail

Tags: sendmail

How can I figure out the exact order of transformations and milters in my sendmail setup?

My problem is that I'm getting mail for a deleted account, and it's being spam checked, despite the fact that it ought to tossed the moment it knows the recipient.

Comment: What is reported by the following debug command (executed by root)?  `echo "3,0 deleted_mailbox_name@your.domain" | sendmail -bt`

Comment: It parses down to a local name, but so does a username which has never existed on my box.

Comment: Does `sendmail -bv mailbox_name@your.domain` produce different results?  Does "deleted account" mean "deleted **OS** account" or "deleted email account"?

Comment: On my box a deleted OS account is also a deleted mail account.
-bv gives back "User Unknown"

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall milters get executed in the order they're defined. i.e. `InputMailFilters=milter1, milter2`, as do all rules in the `sendmail.cf` configuration file.

I has been ages since I last configured sendmail and that was always a complete PITA for all things not standard (and even then). As far as I remember sendmail would not check the existence for a recipient immediately, but if the domain is local would accept the message during the SMTP dialog  and then do further processing and send a bounce later if the specific user is found to be invalid. That might be the reason your milters get executed even for invalid recipients.

For from ideal, but your best bet might be to enable the `blacklist_recipients` as IIRC that is a test that gets performed during the SMTP dialog and should prevent the message for named invalid recipients from getting accepted in the first place. Sendmail should reject mail for thus addresses during the SMTP dialog and not do any further processing all:

```
 FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')
```

then you can add entries to the [`access` map](https://www.sendmail.org/%7Eca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/anti_spam.html#access_db)  for local users and/or addresses in your domain, where the user has been deleted and which should no longer receive mail:

```
 badlocaluser@                  ERROR:550 Mailbox disabled for this username
 deleteduser@example.com        ERROR:550 Mailbox disabled for this username
```

That adds some overhead as you need to both disable user accounts as well as  "document" them as deleted in the access table.

Comment: Hadn't thought of putting the ex-user into access, trying that.

Comment: blacklist has been enabled for a long time for the Greet Pause facility. And it is before any of the milters.

Comment: Oooooh, I think you might have solved a different problem for me. Spamassassin never seemed to care about DKIM. Maybe I know why now...

Comment: Or not. Hmmm. Didn't really change anything in the X-Spam-Status. Oh well. If the usual noon time run of crap come, it'll be a more complete test.

Comment: That’s too bad. Good luck with your further investigations

Comment: Yeah, adding the account to the access map did nothing, sadly.